# Где ошибся в запросе MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь выполнить запрос, но все время выдает ошибку:

```
    INSERT INTO mod (user_id, data1, data2, mod ) VALUES ('1', '2015-01-05 13:23:26','2015-01-06 13:23:26', 'mod1')

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mod (user_id, data1, data2, mod ) VALUES ('1', '2015-01-05 13:23:26','2' at line 1
```

Сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mod` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data1` datetime NOT NULL,
  `data2` datetime NOT NULL,
  `mod` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Код, который выполняется:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
$d = new DateTime($date);
$d->modify("+1 day");
$date2= date_format($d, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
$query = "INSERT INTO mod (user_id, data1, data2, mod )VALUES ('$id_user', '$today','$date2', 'mod1')";
    echo $query.'<br>';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());;
```

---

**Попытался просто выполнить запрос через myadmin**:

```
INSERT INTO mod (user_id, data1, data2, modd ) VALUES ('', '2015-01-05 14:08:41','2015-01-06 14:08:41', 'mod1');
```

Ошибка та же... Может, формат даты неверный?

Новый код формирования запроса тоже дает ошибку: (((

```
$date_today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date_yesterday = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") + 1) ).date(" H:i:s");

$query = "INSERT INTO mod (user_id, data1, data2, modd ) VALUES ('$id_user', '$date_today','$date_yesterday', 'mod1')";
 echo $query.'<br>';
```

---

переименовал таблицу на mod2, **все выполнилось нормально**! Странно )))

Comment: если правильно понял, у вас дважды указывается имя mod (как имя таблицы и столбца), поэтому мускуль в непонятках

Comment: @Etki переименовал второе имя mod, ошибка та же...

Comment: Судя по месту обрыва, у вас проблема с data2, может, потому что вы намешали при работе с ней объектно-ориентированный и процедурный стили? Попробуйте привести манипуляции с этой датой к одному стилю: http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php

Comment: @MasterAlex Попытался просто выполнить запрос через myadmin

INSERT INTO mod (user_id, data1, data2, modd ) VALUES ('', '2015-01-05 14:08:41','2015-01-06 14:08:41', 'mod1');

Ошибка таже... может формат даты не верный?

Comment: Оппа, "modd" :)

Comment: @arashvg, тогда бы была совсем другая ошибка. На самом деле он ругается на конструкцию, которая заканчивается на `INTO`, что мне абсолютно непонятно. Попробуйте написать и выполнить запрос руками с нуля.

Comment: @Etki, переименовал таблицу на mod2, все выполнилось нормально! Странно )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$date1= $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$d->modify("+1 day");
$date2= $d->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$pdo = new PDO(....);
$sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mod (`user_id`, `data1`, `data2`, `mod`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
$sth->execute(array($id_user, $date1, $date2, 'mod1'));
```

P.S. Используйте, пожалуйста, PDO для работы с БД.

Comment: Ваш код у меня вобще не выполнился....

Comment: @arashvg, если не выполнился, то зачем ответ приняли?

Answer (score 1):

> странно но проблема решилась банальным
> переименованием таблицы на mod2

Решилась потому-то слово mod вероятно зарезервировано и в коде реально не хватает кавычек именно таких: ``, ставьте их! Так не будет ошибок никогда, да и вам самим будет легче понимать свой код!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `mod` (`user_id`, `data1`, `data2`, `mod` )
```

VALUES ('1', '2015-01-05 13:23:26',
'2015-01-06 13:23:26', 'mod1')

вся проблема в отсутствии символов ``

Comment: странно, но проблема решилась банальным переименованием таблицы на mod2